# Get log of a systemd/journald in a docker container to "docker logs"

Tags: docker, containers, systemd

I am running a systemd in a docker container.

I want to get all the messages logged by jounrnald, when i use

```
docker logs <containername>
```

Right now the whole messages goe into the journal *in* the container and *nothing* appears when i use "docker logs". How can i turn this off or redirect so that everything appears in docker logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the container with systemd with tty allocated:

```
docker run -t ...
```

Then, inside of the container, edit `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` file with:

```
ForwardToConsole=yes
```

Now just restart `systemd-journald` inside of the container and you should be good to go:

```
systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, I'm still getting nothing on the Docker output.

Comment: I guess this is the reason why it doesn't work currently: [https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1373780#c4](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1373780#c4) Hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: There a note in the systemd man page on why (and how) to avoid doing that: `Unless actively debugging/developing something, it's generally preferable to setup a journalctl --follow style service redirected to the console, instead of ForwardToConsole=yes, for production use.`